# Eclipse photon always resets key bindings on restart

Tags: eclipse, customization

I do use Eclipse IDE for Java already for a long time and never something like that happened yet. My issue for now is that I customized some key bindings, but when I close Eclipse for any reason, the key binding settings are resetted and I need to customize it again.

here is the version information:

> Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers 
>   Version: Photon Release (4.8.0)
>   
>  Build id: 20180619-1200